# sending data to external api in json format as http post

Tags: json, api, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfhttp

I need to send data to an external API in the following JSON format.

I would appreciate some assistance with the correct ColdFusion syntax I need to use with my CFHTTP in order to achieve this.

The searches I have found online appear to be far to overkill complicated for what I require

```
{
  "customer": {
    "first_name": "Steve",
    "last_name": "Lastnameson",
    "email": "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
    "phone": "+15142546011",
    "verified_email": true,
    "addresses": [
      {
        "address1": "123 Oak St",
        "city": "Ottawa",
        "province": "ON",
        "phone": "555-1212",
        "zip": "123 ABC",
        "last_name": "Lastnameson",
        "first_name": "Mother",
        "country": "CA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail here is a generic example that should get you started.

First create your JSON data and store it in a variable:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="JSONData">
{
  "customer": {
    "first_name": "Steve",
    "last_name": "Lastnameson",
    "email": "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
    "phone": "+15142546011",
    "verified_email": true,
    "addresses": [
      {
    "address1": "123 Oak St",
    "city": "Ottawa",
    "province": "ON",
    "phone": "555-1212",
    "zip": "123 ABC",
    "last_name": "Lastnameson",
    "first_name": "Mother",
    "country": "CA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then submit that variable to the api:

```
<cfhttp url="https://somedomain.com/api-specific-uri" method="post" timeout="30">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#Len(Trim(JSONData))#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#Trim(JSONData)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Then for testing you can dump out the results of the HTTP call:

```
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#" />
```

*Note that this is pseudo code and has not really been tested and you may not need all of those headers or you may need more*

Comment: Alternatively, you could build the data using real data structures and then use SerializeJSON() to turn it into text. I like that approach better because your data is validated.

Comment: Agreed but sometimes ColdFusion does not format the JSON to what the API is expecting.  Just be aware of that too.

Comment: That can happen if you don’t put quotes around your property names. I’ve always been able to work around any idiosyncrasies with the resulting JSON, but overall I think it’s a better strategy than building your JSON string manually.